# How to insert data into database column having data type as DBCLOB using java?

Tags: java, db2, ibm-midrange, clob

I have a java gui which i have made using java swing and also i have as400 as back-end database.
I have one column name as ITEMDESE which is having data type as DBCLOB.
Now i need to insert data into that column through java gui(jTextArea).
Please help me.

I have tried by making object of Clob as Clob clob=con.createClob();.
But did not meet my expectations.

```
     String host="10.97.65.6";
     String userid="A40146032";
     String pwd="RAN@001";        

    int itemno =Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
    String itemdesg=jTextArea1.getText();
    String itemdese=jTextArea2.getText();
    double itemrate=Double.parseDouble(jTextField2.getText());      
    //StringBuffer buffer=new StringBuffer(5000);
    //     String fileName=null;
    //        byte[] item_image=null;
    //        WritableRaster raster;
    //        ImageIcon photo;
    //File image=null;            
        try{               
        Class.forName("com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:as400://" + host, userid, pwd);
        System.out.println("Connected!");            
    //            Clob clob=con.createClob();
    //            Writer clobWriter=clob.setCharacterStream(1);
    //            String str=jTextArea2.getText();
    //            clob.setString(1, str);    
        PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO A40146032.DITEM1 (ITEMNO,ITEMDESG,ITEMDESE,ITEMRATE)VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
        ps.setInt(1,itemno);
        //ps.setBinaryStream(2, f);
        //ps.setBytes(2, extractBytes);
        ps.setString(2,itemdesg);
        ps.setString(3, itemdese);
        //ps.setClob(3, con.createClob());
        ps.setDouble(4, itemrate);
        //ps.setBlob(itemno, blob);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data has been successfully added to the database!");
     ps.executeUpdate();
             System.out.println("Query Executed!");
        con.close(); //close connection
        ps.close();
        System.out.println("Connection Closed!");
    }
        catch(Exception e){
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
                }
```

Comment: What do you mean "But did not meet my expectations" ?  EDIT your question to add the explanation. From the "Db2 for i" KC "DBCLOBs are similar to CLOBs except for their internal storage representation of the character data. Because Java and JDBC externalize all character data as Unicode, there is only support in JDBC for CLOBs. DBCLOBs work interchangeable with the CLOB support from a JDBC perspective."

Comment: meaning of my question is that i need to insert data through jTextArea into database which is having one column whose data type is CLOB

Comment: Get the sample program working (adjust the column datatype to DBCLOB), and explain clearly what it not working with the sample for your version of i-series, and your jdbc driver.  The sample program is at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_74/rzaha/putgetclobs.htm

Comment: Ok let me check that thanks mao